# What options do I have when I want to store data from an application locally and without external dependencies?

Tags: c++, performance, data-storage

I am designing an application which ofcourse needs data storage (e.g. user accounts, logs, etc). I don't want performance to be a problem so the retrieval/update/removal of data will be in a separate thread from the main application thread (creator-consumer model).

I cannot use NoSQL databases or any other database-system because they need an external application to be running to make the data available (e.g. with a network pipe to a host).

Yet I need my data to available withouth the need of running another application, so I want to integrate a system into my own application.

I have looked around for databases which can be integrated but I cannot find any.

- Are there any available for simple insert, update, remove operations
  project only?
- Or do I need to stick with flat files because there is
  no independable data storage library which I can integrate? (eg make
  a class and define file writing functions there for my data storage)
- What are my other options?

Side Note: I know it would be kind of stupid, but actually one of my options: is there a SQL (PostgreSQL preferably) database which I can compile along with my project and then issue queries locally?

Comment: Are you looking for an embedded database http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database?

Comment: I think that is what I'm looking for, I don't know english very well but Embedded Database sounds quite correct. Would be cool if there is a Embedded ORM Database for C++, will search for it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> databases [...] need an external application

Wrong. There are plenty in-process database systems (for example [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) which, with a little care, can be made fully ACID compliant).

> is there a SQL (PostgreSQL preferably) database which I can compile along with my project and then issue queries locally?

Well I started answering before you added that remark, but again SQLite comes to mind. If this particular DB doesn't fit you, you may want to search for either "*embedded database*" or "*in-process database*", there are tons of similar products -- either SQL or even NoSQL ones.

One good NoSQL, key-value DB would be [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) but I'm afraid the license has tightened since Oracle bought it so I'm not sure if it's still relevant nowadays (unless your app is fully open-source or you can buy a commercial license).

Comment: Ah, yes I found something called "ODB" which is ORM and has support for SQLite, thanks :) Can accept answer in 4 minutes.

Comment: The big advantage of SQLite, IMHO, is that it is fully public domain so there are no licensing issues. And it's decent enough for small data storage (again, even if you need ACID and multi-client concurrency, at the cost of very little additional work).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good job for [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about SQLite? It does not need any special and complex dependencies. It's fairly easy to setup and use.